# Why does my app crash when I open it for the second time?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

When I install my app on my device through Android Studio, everything is ok, but when I close the app, and try to reopen it, the app crash. I have also tried to do a new project with the same project but everytime I obtain the same problem. I don't use a complicated code but don't knwow why this happens.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9223212 byte allocation with 5451732 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:741)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:562)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3702)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3575)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:750)
        at com.blunderer.materialdesignlibrary.views.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:58)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
        at it.quotidianiitaliani.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Memory Issue. Try managing your app memory heap.

Comment: You request a 8.8M memory when View.setContentView. Check resource images size first.

Comment: Do you run the emulator or a real device? It may be a solution to set "use largeHeap" to true in the manifest.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myerOO5Gr38

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemoryError is the most common problem occur in android while especially dealing with bitmaps. This error is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when an object cannot be allocated due to lack of memory space and also, the garbage collector cannot free some space.

I think you should read some at Androids Developer page, specially here:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html